# Set tableview row height to label height

Tags: xcode, swift, height, uitableview

I have a label and an image.

```
if image != nil {
  cell height = 445
} else {
  //how do i set the cell height according to the label?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the height of tableView cells in `heightForRowAt`. This function returns the height of the cell for a given indexPath (as you probably have guessed). Inside there you can use `return label.frame.height`

In Swift 3:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
if image != nil {
    return 445
  } else {
    return label.frame.height
  }
}
```

**Edit:** You can't use `cellForRowAt` until cells are initialized in `cellForRowAt`. So Try this instead. **It assumes the image and label are** `@IBOutlets`

Comment: It's not working... here is my tableview func: `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: Please post your function in your question so it can be properly formatted. Also, are the label and image properties on a `UITableViewCell` subclass? If not, where are they declared? @johnjay22113

Comment: @Ike10: `cellForRow(at:)` returns nil if the cell isn't visible or `indexPath` is out of range, however, calling `cellForRow(at:)` from inside `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` crashes the app (even if all cells have been initialized) due to some sort of odd recursive call of `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` - actually I don't fully understand this behavior. `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` doesn’t cause an error but I’d say as a method of `UITableViewDataSource` it’s not intended to be used in this way - do you agree on that?